# Janrain engage without displaying the widget

Tags: internet-explorer, janrain

Is there any way to use the engage free APIs to authenticate to a provider without the widget?

My problem I am trying to implement authentication from a Windows Phone app, and the WebBrowser control does not seem to render well the widget content.

It works fine in the IE10 webbrowser app though. The problems are due to WebBrowser control not being able to displat mixed resources from http to https